# Impala - How to get always the next entry from a specific column

Tags: sql, impala

I have a query which is working good at all. But I struggle with a specific problem.

```
WITH x AS(
SELECT
    delivery_slot_from_hour,
    tour_id
FROM my_table
WHERE substr(delivery_slot_from,1,10) = from_timestamp(now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
)
SELECT
    'Current' AS tour_status,
    delivery_slot_from_hour AS delivery_slot,
    COUNT(DISTINCT tour_id) AS tour_count
FROM x
WHERE CAST(substr(delivery_slot_from_hour,1,2) AS INT) = hour(date_trunc('hour',from_utc_timestamp(now(), 'MYRegion')))
GROUP BY delivery_slot
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Current' AS tour_status,
    delivery_slot_from_hour AS delivery_slot,
    COUNT(DISTINCT tour_id) AS tour_count
FROM x
WHERE CAST(substr(delivery_slot_from_hour,1,2) AS INT) = hour(date_trunc('hour',from_utc_timestamp(now(), 'MYRegion')))+1
GROUP BY delivery_slot
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Upcoming' AS tour_status,
    '-' AS delivery_slot,
    COUNT(DISTINCT tour_id) AS tour_count
FROM x
WHERE CAST(substr(delivery_slot_from_hour,1,2) AS INT) > hour(date_trunc('hour',from_utc_timestamp(now(), 'MYRegion')))+1
GROUP BY tour_status;
```

The DELIVERY_SLOT_FROM_HOUR column contains just hour data as STRING like:

```
|delivery_slot|
|-------------|
|10:00        |
|11:00        |
|12:00        |
|13:00        |
```

But this hours must not be ongoing, it is possible that first came 10:00, then 12:00, 13:00, 15:00 and so on.
Example:

```
|delivery_slot|
|-------------|
|10:00        |
|12:00        |
|13:00        |
|15:00        |
```

What I want to have as output should be the current delivery_slot first, than the next one and all other should be 'upcoming'.
So my query is only working if the delivery_slot is ongoing but not if a hour is missing between the current one and the next one.

How can I rewrite this query that I get the correct output? The output for the query with the data from the example table should be:

```
|tour_status|delivery_slot|tour_count|
|-----------|-------------|----------|
|Current    |10:00        |2         |
|Current    |12:00        |13        |
|Upcoming   |-            |50        |
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CTE select all the candidate records and use a window function to create a rank column.

In another CTE select the first record you want to use and it’s rank. Then in your main query select that record and then the record from your first CTE with a rank value 1 greater